# Is there a way to reduce the size of the window launched by NSWorkSpace?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsworkspace

I use this line to open a url in browser.

```
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURL: [NSURL URLWithString:url]];
```

I want to reduce the size of the window created by NSWorkspace.Is it possible programatically?

Comment: I don't think that NSWorkspace has created that window you speak of. openURL launches the default WebBrowser which can be selected in Safari's Preferences (and may be otherwise). So you want to resize a window of a web browser. True?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NSWorkspace does not provide any api to resize the window. But if you are using webview and loading the request inside that then you can resize that webview window.